# Need to get the logon user's ID in html page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to get the logon user's id .
My requirement is : **THere will be a link.(an html page). When the user clicks on that link, the user's logon id will be displayed in the page.**

I have implemented this logic in **classic asp by 
request.servervariables( logon_user )**

But I want to know how to implement it in HTML

Comment: What the heck is a logon user's id?

Answer (score 1):

HTML is client side, so its parsed on the browser. Any information like username, password, id, etc.. must be dealt with on the server side. Only a server side language as ASP.NET/PHP/Python etc can do that. You *could* do it with Javascript/Jquery but without any safety or security since everyone is able to read all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by using HTML. You need to use any kind of server side language to do that. Or you can also use `HTML5 local storage` to meet this specification.